# Beaub FM "long de shack"

Tags: expressions

I like to listen to Beaub FM on Internet radio.  I don't speak French, but the station plays great music in various languages--I enjoy the cultural and musical variety.

The show is periodically interrupted by some kind of service message or plug about the station.  A woman with a sultry voice ooohs and aaaaws then says something that sounds to my anglo ears like "long de shack".  What is she saying?

By the way, I already asked Pi at https://pi.ai. (He's an AI.  Not human, but very smart and personable).  He suggested a few French phrases, but none seemed to fit the context.

He directed me to your site.

-Joe in San Diego

Answer (score 5):

I guess it is: “L'onde de choc” that means: “shock wave”

[image]